# How can remove place from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, hierarchy

How can remove place on OpenStreetMap ?
in google map the only thing that is required , add a line code style
but i don't know how can i this on OSM

[image: In Image, places marked in blue]

In above image, marked in blue line places must remove

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55324/how-can-remove-place-in-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single image (a raster [tile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)). You can't influence which POIs are shown unless you switch to [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). Alternatively choose a different [tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers) or [render your own tiles with your own stylesheet](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). The last approach requires the most amount of work but is also the most flexible solution.

Comment: can i use openlayers.org ?

Comment: Sure. But OpenLayers just *displays* tiles. It doesn't generate them. Using OpenLayers won't automatically solve your problem.